# Coded UI Test Builder: Verification of Text property in Textboxes

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, coded-ui-tests

I use Coded UI Test Builder to create automated manual user input test on a WPF applcation.

In one of my tests many textboxes of Setting dialog box must filled with different values. At the end the settings must be saved.

Later the newly saved settings have be opened again and the current settings in the textboxes must be verified.

It's no problem to create a automated manual input of the settings and save the input.

But I see now way to test the values of the textboxes after saving the new settings.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The Coded UI Test Builder provides the ability to add assertions on the UI controls.

Check this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286671.aspx